# Semaphore in Ada

Tags: embedded, real-time, semaphore, ada, producer-consumer

This is an assignment and I have been asked to implement a Semaphore in Ada as the description below.

However I have implemented the `Semaphore.adb` and called this Semaphore in the  `producerconsumer_sem.adb` which I created.

I get some output which is the following.

1. I'm not sure if my initialization of semaphore is correct `S: CountingSemaphore(1,1);`.
2. I don't know where I call the `S.wait` and `S.Signal` now i randomly called the `S.wait` before Producer put item in the buffer `X := I;` and the `S.Signal` after the `X := I;`.
   Is this the correct way?

> > Producer-Consumer Problem
> >     The program `producerconsumer.adb` implements a non-reliable implemen-
> >     tation of the producer-consumer problem, where data is likely be lost. In
> >     the following, you will use three different communication mechanisms to
> >     achieve a reliable implementation of the producer-consumer problem.
> >
> > **Semaphore**
> >
> > The Ada language does not directly provide library functions for a semaphore.
> >     However, semaphores can be implemented by means of a protected object. Create a package specification Semaphore in the file Semaphores.ads
> >     and the corresponding package body in the file `Semaphores.adb` that
> >     implements a counting semaphore. Skeletons for the package are available on the course page.
> >
> > Use the semaphore package for a reliable implementation of the producer-
> >     consumer problem. Modify the file `producerconsumer.adb` and save the
> >     final code as `producerconsumer_sem.adb`. In order to use the semaphore
> >     package it shall be installed in the same directory as `producerconsumer_sem.adb`.
> >     It can then be accessed by
> >
> > `with Semaphores;`
> >     `use Semaphores;`

The Output:

> > **OutPut:**
> >      1
> >      1
> >      1
> >      2
> >      2
> >      3
> >      4
> >      4
> >      5
> >      6
> >      6
> >      7
> >      7
> >      8
> >      9
> >      9
> >      9
> >      10
> >      11
> >      11
> >      11
> >      12
> >      12
> >      13
> >      13
> >      13
> >      14
> >      15
> >      15
> >      16
> >      16
> >      17
> >      18
> >      18
> >      18
> >      19
> >      20
> >      20
> >      21
> >      21
> >      22
> >      22
> >      23
> >      24
> >      24
> >      24
> >      24
> >      25
> >      25
> >      26
> >      27
> >      27
> >      28
> >      29
> >      29
> >      30
> >      30
> >      31
> >      31
> >      32
> >      32
> >      33
> >      33
> >      33
> >      34
> >      35
> >      35
> >      35
> >      36
> >      36
> >      37
> >      37
> >      37
> >      38
> >      38
> >      38
> >      39
> >      40
> >      40
> >      40

The package

```
package Semaphores is
   protected type CountingSemaphore(Max: Natural; Initial: Natural)  is
      entry Wait;
      entry Signal;
   private
      Count : Natural := Initial;
      MaxCount : Natural := Max;
   end CountingSemaphore;
end Semaphores;
```

The Semaphore I implemented `semaphores.adb`.

```
package body Semaphores is
   protected body CountingSemaphore is
   entry Wait when Count > 0 is
    begin
    Count := Count - 1;

    end Wait;
      entry Signal when Count < MaxCount is
    begin
    Count := Count + 1;

    end Signal;
   end CountingSemaphore;
end Semaphores;
```

The `producerconsumer_sem.adb`

```
with Ada.Text_IO;
use Ada.Text_IO;

with Ada.Real_Time;
use Ada.Real_Time;

with Ada.Numerics.Discrete_Random;

with Semaphores;
use Semaphores;

procedure ProducerConsumer_sem is

   X : Integer; -- Shared Variable
   N : constant Integer := 40; -- Number of produced and comsumed variables

   S: CountingSemaphore(1,1);
   --S1: CountingSemaphore(1,1);

   pragma Volatile(X); -- For a volatile object all reads and updates of
                       -- the object as a whole are performed directly
                       -- to memory (Ada Reference Manual, C.6)

   --Random Delays
   subtype Delay_Interval is Integer range 50..250;
   package Random_Delay is new Ada.Numerics.Discrete_Random
   (Delay_Interval);
   use Random_Delay;
   G : Generator;

   task Producer;

   task Consumer;

   task body Producer is
      Next : Time;
   begin
      Next := Clock;
      for I in 1..N loop
         -- Write to X
         S.Wait;
         X := I;
         S.Signal;
         --Next 'Release' in 50..250ms
         Next := Next + Milliseconds(Random(G));
         Put_Line(Integer'Image(X));
         delay until Next;
      end loop;
   end;

   task body Consumer is
      Next : Time;
   begin
      Next := Clock;
      for I in 1..N loop
         -- Read from X
         S.Wait;
         Put_Line(Integer'Image(X));
         S.Signal;
         Next := Next + Milliseconds(Random(G));
         delay until Next;
      end loop;
   end;

begin -- main task


   null;
end ProducerConsumer_sem;
```

Comment: I suggest that you clean up your sources (proper indentation, no left-over comments, Ada-style identifiers) and present the package specification before its implementation.

Comment: @JacobSparreAndersen i edited thanks for mentioning.

Comment: You say "I get some output which is the following" but it’s not there.

Comment: @SimonWright the output is in the description part value from 1 to 40 if you look at the section with yellow color, maybe bad place i put that sorry.

Comment: Oh, I thought that was part of the question

Comment: actually im unsure about if the output is correct please have a look if the output is saying something

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On macOS, with FSF GCC 7.1.0 and GNAT GPL 2017, I changed your `Put_Line`s to `Put`s and got pretty-much the answer you state in the question.

The question says to create `Semaphore.ads`, `.adb`. This will work on Windows, and may work on macOS, but won’t work on Linux, because of GNAT’s file naming convention (see the end of [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gnat_ugn/File-Naming-Rules.html#File-Naming-Rules); it’s a good idea to get into the habit of using lower-case file names).

If you want to ensure that only one task has access to `X` at a time, I don’t think there’s much wrong with your `Wait`, `Signal` calls, though when I put a `delay 0.1` at the beginning of `Producer`, the first value output was 151619216 (because `X` isn’t initialized). However! if the point is to communicate one update to X at a time (as implied by the names producer/consumer), you should

- initialize the semaphore with a count of 0 (and a max of 1). This makes it a binary semaphore.
- in `Consumer`, `Wait` only (i.e. remove the `Signal`)
- in `Producer`, `Signal` only (i.e. remove the `Wait`). Also, remove the `Put` to avoid confusion!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately the teacher want me to compile and run this in Linux with `gnatmake` command, I'm very new to Ada don't much. But this is very interesting point you mention if it's won't work on Linux. do you mean that this will not compile in Linux or it will not give correct output?.  I run this as the teacher mention with command `gnatmake producercomsumer.adb` and `./producerconsumer`  in ubuntu 16  which gives the that out output in the yellow section but not sure if that output is correct or what it is.

Comment: If I initialize count to 0 and max to 40 does this mean that it is counting semaphore?

Comment: It will work fine if you call the files `semaphore.ads` & `.adb`, not `Semaphore` (well, put it this way, if you got it to work with capitalized names I Am Amazed). As to "correct" - it’s supposed to be a reliable producer-consumer, but 39 is produced and not consumed! Also, 40 is produced but consumed twice. So I’d guess not. A `Max` of 40 would be counting.

Comment: You are completely right. That was a typo from the instructor in assignment text which also influenced on me. But the skeleton they handed over me is all packages are in small letter also(`semaphore.ads`) sorry.

Comment: Any idea how to make it reliable with counting Semaphore?. Should I just test to initialize it for different `max` value and `count ` value?